# inject required dependency to a bind directly in the register method

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection

This is my register method. I have two binds. The second CaptionOrderSubmission is the one that interest me.

```
public function register()
{
    $clientKey = env('REV_CLIENT_API_KEY');
    $userKey = env('REV_USER_API_KEY');
    $endPoint = env('REV_URL_END_POINT');

    App::bind('RevAPI\Rev', function($app) use($clientKey, $userKey, $endPoint)
    {
        return new Rev($clientKey, $userKey, $endPoint);
    });

    App::bind('RevAPI\CaptionOrderSubmission', function($app) use($clientKey, $userKey, $endPoint)
    {
        $rev = new Rev($clientKey, $userKey, $endPoint);
        return new CaptionOrderSubmission($rev);
    });

}
```

How can I do something like?

```
public function register()
{
    $clientKey = env('REV_CLIENT_API_KEY');
    $userKey = env('REV_USER_API_KEY');
    $endPoint = env('REV_URL_END_POINT');

    App::bind('RevAPI\Rev', function($app) use($clientKey, $userKey, $endPoint)
    {
        return new Rev($clientKey, $userKey, $endPoint);
    });

    App::bind('RevAPI\CaptionOrderSubmission', function($app) use(RevApi/Rev $rev)
    {
        return new CaptionOrderSubmission($rev);
    });
```

}

is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution
in the second bind you can do

```
App::bind('RevAPI\CaptionOrderSubmission', function($app)
{
    $rev = $app->make("RevApi\Rev");    
    return new CaptionOrderSubmission($rev);
});
```